# How do I detect what process modified a file in Windows using Powershell Events?

Tags: powershell, filesystems, ntfs

I know that you can monitor a file or directory by subscribing to events from Windows in Powershell; but how do I tell what process / pid made the change?

```
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $FileSystemWatcher  -EventName Created  -Action {

   $Object  = "{0} was  {1} at {2}" -f $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath,

   $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType,

   $Event.TimeGenerated

   $WriteHostParams  = @{

   ForegroundColor = 'Green'

   BackgroundColor =  'Black'

   Object =  $Object

   }

   Write-Host $Event | Get-Member -Type Properties,Method,MemberSet,Event

}
```

Comment: Have you considered NTFS audit policy?

Comment: @alexzelaya Does it tell you what process modified the file?

Comment: Yes. It will raise an event that you could potentially launch an action against via Tash Scheduler/monitor/etc. It's quite granular so you can even configure it just for a specific file/folder. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/apply-a-basic-audit-policy-on-a-file-or-folder